# When using 2 datasources, how to inject interceptors with repositories that are attached to the datasource of choice?

Tags: loopback4

I am using a test datasource that is separate from my development datasource.
I have an interceptor with a repository injection like this:

```
export class MyGlobalInterceptor implements Provider<Interceptor> {
  constructor(
    @repository(MyRepository)
    public myRepo: MyRepository,
  ) {}

  value() {
    return this.intercept.bind(this);
  }

  async intercept(
    invocationCtx: InvocationContext,
    next: () => ValueOrPromise<InvocationResult>,
  ) {
    // ... do something with this.myRepo, e.g. validate a token
    return next();
  }
}
```

When running acceptance tests the interceptor is injected with a development datasource repository.
Is there a way to attach the repository to the test datasource instead ?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using cross-env to set NODE_ENV to "test" during test runs:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "cross-env-shell NODE_ENV=test \"npm run clean && npm run build && lb-mocha --allow-console-logs --exit \"dist/__tests__\"\"",
},
```

And because both my main and test datasorces are mongodb, I was able to do this in my src/datasources/mongodb.datasource.ts

```
const mainConfig = {
  name: 'main',
  connector: 'mongodb',
  database: process.env.MONGODB_DATABASE,
  // host, port, user, password, etc.
};

const testConfig = {
  name: 'test',
  connector: 'mongodb',
  database: process.env.MONGODB_TEST_DATABASE,
  // host, port, user, password, etc.
};

// this is the important part
const config = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test' ? testConfig : mainConfig;

// the rest is unchanged cli generated code
@lifeCycleObserver('datasource')
export class MongodbDataSource extends juggler.DataSource
  implements LifeCycleObserver {
  static dataSourceName = 'mongodb';
  static readonly defaultConfig = config;

  constructor(
    @inject('datasources.config.mongodb', { optional: true })
    dsConfig: object = config,
  ) {
    super(dsConfig);
  }
}
```

I'm not a fan of this solution, because ideally I would want everything test related to be contained in src/__tests__ and not appear anywhere else.
If there's a better way to do this, please let me know.